# Does Sqoop incremental lastmodified option include the date, mentioned in last value, in result?

Tags: sqoop

My SQL table is

mysql> select * from Orders;

+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+

| ord_no | purch_amt | ord_date   | customer_id | salesman_id |

+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+

|  70001 |    150.50 | 2012-10-05 |        3005 |        5002 |

|  70009 |    270.65 | 2012-09-10 |        3001 |        5005 |

|  70002 |     65.26 | 2012-10-05 |        3002 |        5001 |

|  70004 |    110.50 | 2012-08-17 |        3009 |        5003 |

|  70007 |    948.50 | 2012-09-10 |        3005 |        5002 |

|  70005 |    999.99 | 2012-07-27 |        3007 |        5001 |

|  70008 |    999.99 | 2012-09-10 |        3002 |        5001 |

|  70010 |    999.99 | 2012-10-10 |        3004 |        5006 |

|  70003 |    999.99 | 2012-10-10 |        3009 |        5003 |

|  70012 |    250.45 | 2012-06-27 |        3008 |        5002 |

|  70011 |     75.29 | 2012-08-17 |        3003 |        5007 |

|  70013 |    999.99 | 2012-04-25 |        3002 |        5001 |

+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+

I ran an Sqoop import

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://ip-172-31-20-247:3306/sqoopex -- 
username sqoopuser --password <hidden> --table Orders --target-dir 
SqoopImp2 --split-by ord_no --check-column ord_date --incremental 
lastmodified --last-value '2012-09-10'
```

As per Sqoop 1.4.6 manual stated below,

> An alternate table update strategy supported by Sqoop is called lastmodified 
>    mode. You should use this when rows of the source table may be updated, and each such update will set the value of a last-modified column to the current timestamp. Rows where **the check column holds a timestamp more recent than the timestamp specified with --last-value** are imported

I was not expecting columns with date '2012-09-10' in output. However my output, as shown below,

[manojpurohit17834325@ip-172-31-38-146 ~]$ hadoop fs -cat SqoopImp2/*

70001,150.50,2012-10-05,3005,5002

70002,65.26,2012-10-05,3002,5001

70003,999.99,2012-10-10,3009,5003

70007,948.50,2012-09-10,3005,5002

70009,270.65,2012-09-10,3001,5005

70008,999.99,2012-09-10,3002,5001

70010,999.99,2012-10-10,3004,5006

contains rows with date 20125-10-10. Note: the output directory was not present earlier and it was created by this sqoop execution.

From this execution, I see that date in --last-modified is included in output which is contrary to what is mentioned in manual. Please help me understand this discrepancy and correct me if am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

**yes**, **--lastvalue** also included in the results.
in --incremental import 2 modes available: i) append ii) lastmodified

**append**: in this mode it just checks --lastvalue and import from last value onwards.
 --> it's not imported any previous values even if they updated

**lastmodified:** it's also the same as append mode only but here it imports new rows and imported previous rows also if they updated. 
Note: lastmodified is working on the only date or Timestamp type columns only